# Jsoup simple HTML tag splitting

Tags: java, pdf, itext, jsoup

My java app reads database rows, and creates iText PDF files. The problem is that some cells in the rows I get, contain the bold HTML tag, and this means that I must also display a bold Chunk in my respective iText Paragraph.

So for example one cell of the DB line may be as follows:

```
This is an <b>important</b> line and i <b>want</b> formatting in it
```

What I am currently doing is simply obtaining the bolds with jsoup

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);
org.jsoup.select.Elements bold = doc.select("B");
System.out.println("[BODY: "+doc.body().text()+"] BOLD:>> " + bold.text());
```

What I really want to do is to split the string, between the bold and the non-bold parts. So a proper solution to my problem would output

```
This is an
<b>important</b>
line and i 
<b>want</b>
formatting in it
```

or something similar, so that i can create my iText Chunks and add to my Paragraph.
Is there any way to do this with Jsoup?

Comment: Can you add a complete text example? Do you have any other tags, or only `<b>` tags?

Comment: I have got only <b> tags. No other tag is present. An actual example is the following line: 
CS999X(26-0A--200005) having <B>ID</B> value = <B>200005</B> 
As you can see there are multiple bold occurrences that need to be turned to Chunks with bold font

Comment: With only bold tags, have you considered using regular expression? This might be a better solution than adding a html parser only for bold elements.

Comment: I have tried to do so, but this would mean that i would need to process the match with start() and end(), and then take the substrings from the original input line which seemed like an overkill. Furthermore i am trying to avoid a scenario where something would not match and i'd have to go and change the regexp numerous times. Also i am trying to be ready in case the data provider decides to add another tag at some point...

Comment: Ok, then it makes sense, was just to be sure you knew that regexp could be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Node`'s instead of `Elements`:

```
final String html = "This is an <b>important</b> line and i <b>want</b> formatting in it";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);


for( Node node : doc.body().childNodes() )
{
    System.out.println(node.toString());
}
```

**Output:**

```
This is an 
<b>important</b>
 line and i 
<b>want</b>
 formatting in it
```

If the leading blanks are a problem, use `node.toString().trim()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what i was looking for. For the sake of other people who may need to do the same, i want to point out that node.nodeName() returns the HTML tag, so the handling of any tag can be programmed

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several solutions to your problem :

- First one, the simplest : you run through all the elements one by one, and for each element, you check if it's a `<b>` tag. To do so : universal selector,a loop for all the [elements](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) and the check to know if the element is a bold [tag](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#tagName%28%29).
- Another one, bit more complex, much more efficient I think if you had several tags : you select the bold as you do, and the non-bold with the not selector : `:not('b')`. You have 2 lists of elements now, but they are not ordered. To retrieve the order you can use [elementSiblingIndex](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#elementSiblingIndex%28%29).

If you want to read more about selectors : http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html