# Split a string in java containing html

Tags: java, string, split, substring

I have a dynamically generated string like :

```
String s = <span><input style='font-weight:bold'>Hello team</input></span>
```

I want to split the string as:

```
String startTag = <span><input style='font-weight:bold'>
String endTag = </input></span>
String content = Hello Team
```

The String **s** can be anything (depending on the code) like

```
<span style='font-weight:bold'>Hello team</span>
```

or

```
<td><input style='font-weight:bold'>Hello team</input></td>
```

So, I want to split based on the index of '>' and '<'?

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Split string on UpperCase Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888238/javascript-split-string-on-uppercase-characters)

Comment: Oh parsing HTML, sounds like a job for regexp!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use a SAX Parser.
Implement your own DefaultHandler and override the following methods :

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)

public void startElement (String uri, String localName,
                              String qName, Attributes attributes)

public void endElement (String uri, String localName, String qName)

If you need help, look this example : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String s = "<td><span><td><input style='font-weight:bold'>Hello team</input></td></span></td>";

  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(<.+>)([a-z A-Z ]+?)(</.+>)$");

  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

  if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
        System.out.println(m.group(3)); 
  }
}
```

This, is gonna work, m.group(0) is the hole string so don't use it
It uses regex : regular expression to catch normalized sentences , you find lots of example on the web, lots of programation languages have their proper rules for regex be careful

Comment: its causing IllegalStateException

Comment: It makes me think of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4370629) everytime I see an answer like that.

Comment: @veraliesim : I don't know when, i tried it before post here, and it was working sorry, i always check before giving an answer ;)

Comment: @Spotted : you find mine not clear ? ^^ I don't, i give only the util part, and working as well

Comment: @azro It's not that I find it unclear nor that I think it doesn't work, it's more that I think you use the wrong tool for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "<span><input style='font-weight:bold'>Hello team</input></span>";
    String sCheck = s;

    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    String startTag="";
    String storedStartTag="";
    String endTag;
    String storedEndTag="";
    boolean foundEnd=false;

    if(s.charAt(0) == '<'){

        for (int i = 0;i<sCheck.length();i++){
            if(sCheck.charAt(i) == '>'){
                j=i;
                startTag = sCheck.substring(0,j+1);
                storedStartTag = storedStartTag + startTag;
                sCheck = sCheck.substring(j+1,sCheck.length());
            }
        }
    }

   for (int i = 0;i<s.length();i++){
            if(s.charAt(i) == '<'){
                if(s.charAt(i+1) == '/'){
                    k=i;
                    foundEnd = true;
                } 
            }
           if (foundEnd == true){
                    if(s.charAt(i) == '>'){
                       endTag = s.substring(k,i+1);
                       storedEndTag = storedEndTag + endTag;
                    }
            }

    }
    System.out.println(storedStartTag);
    System.out.println(storedEndTag);
}}
```

This is without Regex, just tried to solve it, don't judge :))

Answer (score 0):

Use this (single line) to split:

```
String[] parts = s.split("(?<=>)(?=((?!<[^/]).)*$)|(?=</)", 3);
```

This splits the input into an array of size 3:

```
parts[0] // opening tag(s)
parts[1] // content
parts[2] // closing tag(s)
```

It works for any number of wrapping tags.

Comment: Makes me think of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4370629)... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I used the below and it works fine for me. Thanks for the help! :)

```
               int i2 = s.indexOf(">");
            int count = 0;
            LinkedList<Integer> indexes = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            while (i2 >= 0) {
               indexes.add(i2);
               i2 = s.indexOf(">", i2 + 1);
               count ++;
           }
            int i1 = s.indexOf("</");
            int c = count/2;
            int b = indexes.get(c-1);

            String startTag = s.substring(0,b+1);
            String content = s.substring(b+1,i1);
            String endTag = s.substring(i1);
```

Comment: Very bad idea. What if '<' or '>' is used in text? Use jsoup to parse and format it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521429/jsoup-simple-html-tag-splitting